# c++ trying to initialize values in 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, variable-assignment, list-initialization

I have created a 2d array called digits and would like to initialize each of the subarrays one by one to make my code clearer. I understand that the following code works:

```
string digits[2][5] = { { " - ","| |","   ","| |"," - " },{ " - ","| |","   ","| |"," - " } };
```

But am wondering why the following doesn't work:

```
string digits[2][5];
digits[0] = { " - ","| |","   ","| |"," - " };
digits[1] = { " - ", "| |", "   ", "| |", " - " };
```

Comment: It's assignment. Initialize list is only for intialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd one is not initialization, it's assignment (of elements of `digits`).

```
string digits[2][5];                               // initialization
digits[0] = { " - ","| |","   ","| |"," - " };     // assignment of the 1st element of digits
digits[1] = { " - ", "| |", "   ", "| |", " - " }; // assignment of the 2nd element of digits
```

The element of `digits` is an array, the raw [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Assignment) can't be assigned as a whole.

> Objects of array type cannot be modified as a whole: even though they
>   are lvalues (e.g. an address of array can be taken), they cannot
>   appear on the left hand side of an assignment operator

You could do this with `std::array` or `std::vector`, which could be assigned with braced initializer.

```
std::array<std::array<std::string, 5>, 2> digits;
digits[0] = { " - ","| |","   ","| |"," - " };
digits[1] = { " - ", "| |", "   ", "| |", " - " };
```

Answer (score 2):

initialization is far different from assignment. initialization is assigning a value to variable while declaring (invoking constructor) whereas assignment is to declare then assign (invoking assignment operator).
to assign correctly you remove brackets and then you use a loop or manually eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string s[2][3];
    string Hi = "Hi there!";

    s[0][0] = "Hello there!";
    //....

    for(int i(0); i < 2; i++)
        for(int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            s[i][j] = Hi;

    for(int i(0); i < 2; i++)
        for(int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            cout << s[i][j] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're changing this line for clarity, also consider:

```
string digits[2][5] = {
        {" - ", "| |", "   ", "| |", " - "},
        {" - ", "| |", "   ", "| |", " - "}
    };
```

Note: *Consider*. Indentation is a powerful tool, but it can be misused.